# Converting pandas DF into special dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame with customer_id, date, product_id that they bought. I want to convert this DataFrame to 2 dictionary

```
customer_id    date     product_id
1            10/3/2017  1234
2            11/3/2017  4321
1            10/3/2017  7384
2            10/3/2017  1234
```

I want the output like:

```
{'10/3/2017': {1 : 1234, 1: 7384, 2: 1234}, '11/3/2017': {2 : 4321}}
```

I tried to use

```
df.set_index(['date','customer_number']).T.to_dict('record')
```

But it won't give me 2 dictionaries.

```
{('10/3/2017', 1): 1234', .....}
```

Comment: What happened to `7384`?

Comment: It's my mistake. I fixed that @Alex

Comment: @Homesand - `dict` in python has unique keys, so is not possible create `{1 : 1234, 1: 7384}`

Comment: Oh thank you for letting me know that. What if the output is a list instead @jezrael  {1: [1234,7384]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem with duplicates per group in first and third row, so was returned `1: 7384`. Solution use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with lambda function for convert to `dict` per group and then [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) for convert final `Series`:

```
d = df.groupby('date').apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['customer_id'], x['product_id']))).to_dict()
print (d)
{'10/3/2017': {1: 7384, 2: 1234}, '11/3/2017': {2: 4321}}
```

EDIT:

```
s = df.groupby(['date','customer_id'])['product_id'].apply(list)
d = {k: v[k].to_dict() for k, v in s.groupby(level=0)}
print (d)
{'10/3/2017': {1: [1234, 7384], 2: [1234]}, '11/3/2017': {2: [4321]}}
```

And if dont need one item lists:

```
s = (df.groupby(['date','customer_id'])['product_id']
       .apply(lambda x: list(x) if len(x) > 1 else x.iat[0]))
d = {k: v[k].to_dict() for k, v in s.groupby(level=0)}
print (d)
{'10/3/2017': {1: [1234, 7384], 2: 1234}, '11/3/2017': {2: 4321}}
```

Comment: but it will omit 1 value 10/3/2017 : {1:1234}

Comment: @Homesand - it is expected, because it is not possible in `dict` - multiple duplicated keys. But is possible create `{'10/3/2017': {1 : [1234, 7384], 2: 1234}, '11/3/2017': {2 : 4321}}`

Comment: can you help me with that ? I have just saw your comment

Comment: @Homesand not so easy, this is first version

Comment: Thank you so much. I am trying to understand it @jezrael

Answer (score 1):

Adding on the solution by jezrael, you could use **list** inside the apply function instead of **dict** to get the output you need. That way duplicates won't be deleted as we see by using dict.

```
d = df.groupby('date').apply(lambda x: list((zip(x['customer_id'], x['product_id'])))).to_dict()
```

The output is :

```
{'10/3/2017': [(1, 1234), (1, 7384), (2, 1234)], '11/3/2017': [(2, 4321)]}
```