# Converting pandas dataframe to dictionary using "index" option with a non unique column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, `df1`, of 3 million records like this.

`name,address,zipcode
 james,abd sdfse sdfex sdfs,234212
 james,aseesdfwerw asdfasee,234355
 mathew,asfasee sdfadf,43453`

I want to convert it to dictionary, with `name` as the index.

Here's what I did:

`df1.set_index('name',in_place=True)
 dict1=df1.to_dict('index')`

Since `name` is not a unique column, I can see that some of the records get dropped after converting to dictionary. Can anyone help me how to make it a dictionary of lists/some other way of handling it?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: After this step, I want to use the dictionary to compare with another dictionary for mapping one column to another column

Comment: Your question looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49211471/converting-pandas-df-into-special-dictionary/49212228#49212228) answered question. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is create `list`s:

```
d = df.groupby('name').agg(lambda x: x.tolist()).to_dict('index')
print (d)
{'james': {'address': ['abd sdfse sdfex sdfs', 'aseesdfwerw asdfasee'], 
             'zipcode': [234212, 234355]}, 
 'mathew': {'address': ['asfasee sdfadf'], 
            'zipcode': [43453]}}
```