# Group values of a chosen column into a list when creating a dictionary from a pandas data frame with a non-unique index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like his

```
_____________________
|col1 | col2 | col3 |
---------------------
| a   | b    | c    |
| d   | b    | c    |
| e   | f    | g    |
| h   | f    | j    |
---------------------
```

I want to get a dictionary structure that looks as follows

```
{
    b : { col1: [a,d], col2: b, col3: c},
    f : { col1: [e, h], col2: f, col3: [g, j]}
}
```

I have seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49222788/converting-pandas-dataframe-to-dictionary-using-index-option-with-a-non-unique). But it seems like overkill for what I want to do as it converts every value of the key inside the nested dictionary into a list. I would only like to convert `col1` into a list when creating the dictionary. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom lambda function for return unique values in list if there is multiple them else scalar in lambda function:

```
d = (df.set_index('col2', drop=False)
       .groupby(level=0)
       .agg(lambda x: list(set(x)) if len(set(x)) > 1 else list(set(x))[0])
       .to_dict('index'))
print (d)
{'b': {'col1': ['d', 'a'], 'col2': 'b', 'col3': 'c'}, 
 'f': {'col1': ['h', 'e'], 'col2': 'f', 'col3': ['j', 'g']}}
```

If order is important use `dict.fromkeys` for remove duplicates:

```
d = (df.set_index('col2', drop=False)
       .groupby(level=0)
       .agg(lambda x: list(dict.fromkeys(x)) if len(set(x)) > 1 else list(set(x))[0])
       .to_dict('index'))
print (d)
{'b': {'col1': ['a', 'd'], 'col2': 'b', 'col3': 'c'},
 'f': {'col1': ['e', 'h'], 'col2': 'f', 'col3': ['g', 'j']}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Order isn't important for me but I'm sure it will be for someone else